# ZFS zvol refer value grows up when mounted

Tags: zfs

I have 2 question about ZFS.

First is about ZVOL.
I have pool created by two SAS drives (striped).
I create ZVOL in this pool (using command: `zfs create -V 400gb pool/myZvol`) and everythink is OK.
Next, I created a partition on ZVOL using `fdisk` and format it to ext4 filesystem.

Next, I mounted this partition to my directory and now... when I type command `zfs list`, refer column of my ZVOL is every time growing up.
Of course I didn't add any files or directories to the mounted directory. Why is this value growing up?

Second question is about pools disks names/IDs.
When I created the pool using disks paths like `/dev/sda`, sometimes, after reboot, this paths are changed and my pools don't import automatically. So I want to use disks IDs to create pools, but when I type command `ls -la /dev/disk/by-id` I get multiple IDs to one path like:

```
scsi-350000395782a0820 -> ../../sdb
wwn-0x50000395782a0820 -> ../../sdb
```

When I created the pool using disk id, and type `zpool status` I get this:

```
NAME                        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
backups                     ONLINE       0     0     0
  mirror-0                  ONLINE       0     0     0
    wwn-0x5000039fdade44c8  ONLINE       0     0     0
    wwn-0x5000039fd9c52f02  ONLINE       0     0     0
```

But I want to use IDs like `scsi-350000395782a0820`, not like `wwn-0x50000395782a0820`. How can I change this?

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: Hello. So have i to edit this question and add one more?

Comment: indeed, your best course is to create a new question and move the relevant part in there.